# Cloning from Bitbucket to local AndroidStudio project

Tags: git, android-studio, gradle, bitbucket

I have a functional AndroidStudio project on my laptop, and I have managed to upload it to my Bitbucket repository to give me some form of version control. I then wanted to clone it to my desktop from Bitbucket, but AndroidStudio does not recognise the project after pulling it as it does not contain the gradle files (which are automatically added to .gitignore).

Is it safe to remove the .gitignore so I can pull the exact same gradle files?
Or is there a way to build a new gradle file from the pulled project?

I've tried creating a new project to get the gradle files and then copying over the relevant pulled files, but then there are gradle sync files I can't resolve.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, I feel like I'm missing something really simple.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have uploaded project to Bit-bucket and you are unable to open in Android Studio
2. Clone the project from Bit-bucket and remove the required file names from .gitignore file and save file
3. Go to folder from where you have pushed code to bit bucket
4. Copy required files and add those files in project and build project then open in android studio

If you remove .gitignore file then it will not impact much on your code, however you will push unnecessary code into bit bucket.